# problem in deploying in Dialogflow (Inline Editor)

Tags: dialogflow-es

could you please assist to know the reason of theses errors and how to resolve ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is the default script, i have no change and also billing is enabled for this project

Comment: can you paste the code?

Comment: also i noticed this error in chrome
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "userFacingMessage: Permission denied on 'locations/global' (or it may not exist); \ncom.google.cloud.eventprocessing.manager.api.error.InvalidRegionException: userFacingMessage: Permission denied on 'locations/global' (or it may not exist);  Code: PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "userFacingMessage: Permission denied on 'locations/global' (or it may not exist); \ncom.google.cloud.eventprocessing.manager.api.error.InvalidRegionException: userFacingMessage: Permission denied on 'locations/global' (or it may not exist);  Code: PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: so I tried to reproduce the issue by copy/pasting your code but it has deployed successfully. Try using incognito window and update here please.